# Python on RPi 2: two scripts using same variable

Tags: python

I have two python scripts on RPi 2, the first is for capturing images when motion is detected, and the second is for sending the captured images to my mail. The problem is that I don't know how to get these scripts to work together.

Here is the code of the first script:

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
import picamera
import datetime
from pushetta import Pushetta

def get_file_name():
     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpg")

sensor = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state = False
current_state = False

cam = picamera.PiCamera()

API_KEY="key"
CHANNEL_NAME="CzechBery"
p=Pushetta(API_KEY)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    previous_state = current_state
    current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
    if current_state != previous_state:
        new_state = "HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
        print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, new_state))
        if current_state:
            fileName = get_file_name()
            cam.start_preview()
            p.pushMessage(CHANNEL_NAME, "Motion Detected")
            time.sleep(2)
            cam.capture(fileName)
 time.sleep(1)
        else:
            cam.stop_preview()
```

and here is the second:

```
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

fromaddr = 'from'
toaddrs  = 'to'  # can be list of strings
subject = 'Testing'

#
# Email object
#
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddrs
msg['Subject'] = subject

#
# Email body
body = 'Alert!! Motion Detected!!\nTime: %s' % str(datetime.now())
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

#msgText = MIMEText('<b>Some <i>HTML</i> text</b> and an image.<br><img src="cid:image1"><br>Nifty!', 'html')
#msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

fp = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()

# Define the image's ID as referenced above
#msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', 'image')
msg.attach(msgImage)

#
# Connecting to SMTP server and
# sending the email
#
smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login('from','passwd')
text = msg.as_string()
smtp.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, text)
smtp.quit()

#
# Output
#
print "Message sent." + "\n" + "From: " + fromaddr + "\n" + "To: " + toaddrs
```

I need send images created by the first script with the second script, but only when motion is detected. Images are named by this method:

```
def get_file_name():
     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpg")
```

Comment: Why don't you put the content of the second script into a function that you call after you have created an image?

Comment: What's going on? Is it not sending images properly, or do you not understand how to send images?

Comment: yea, i dont know how to send current image which was captured by detector.

Comment: Sorry im idiot, you have right i can put the content of the second into a function. Or i can call function by `from SecondScript import function` and use it in `while` loop. But thanks for comments